# How to query billions of records based on three columns faster in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has 118507658  records.

I have to query records that works faster.
Currently I am using following query to get all records, but it takes very long time. This is the query i am using to fetch the records.

```
select value_id, content_definition_id, order, scope_id, entry_date
from
   (
   select value_id, content_definition_id, order, scope_id, entry_date,
          row_number(*) over (partition by content_definition_id, order, scope_id
                              order by entry_date desc ) as rn
   from temp 
   ) dt
where rn < 3
order by  content_definition_id, order, scope_id;
```

I have created index on content_definition_id, order, scope_id columns also.

After fetching the records I have to insert all these records into a table and then delete existing table also.

Please suggest how to fetch records faster. Do I have to create composite index on content_definition_id, order, scope_id columns? If yes, then how to create?

Comment: You should consider Table Partitioning :https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/scaling-postgresql-performance-table-partitioning

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: First, the table should have a primary key, or at least a candidate key. A subset of `value_id, content_definition_id, order, scope_id, entry_date` looks like a likely natural key. If this subset is smaller than 4 keyfields, your table wasn't in 3NF anyway. BTW: `order` is a bad name for a column; just look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: If this is something that is going to occur over and over, you may benefit from evaluating the resulting data and finding ways to filter data to eliminate known non-contenders.  For example, if your earliest entry date for all of the data is 1/1/13 and will never be before that (any subsequent entries cannot possibly result in new results prior to 1/1/13), you can apply that filter and eliminate potentially large amounts of records from ever having the `row_number()` analytic from applying to them.  This very much comes down to knowing and understanding your data, and it might not be possible

Comment: Also if that's the case, then Code-Monk's comment about partitioning would help **IMMENSELY**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if this is the most important query, I suggest to make this index the CLUSTERED.
2. you have to consider entry_date also in your indexing strategy
3. (SQL Server) create the "index key columns" consisting of all these columns: content_definition_id ,order ,scope_id, entry_date
   and put the value_id as "included column"

Comment: So i have to create index separately on all these columns and then do i have to create CLUSTERED index combining all these?.Can you please help me with the syntax also for CLUSTERED  index.

Comment: for this query, just 1 clustered index having these fields in the "index key columns" .

Comment: CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX  IX_Index_temp
    ON temp (content_definition_id ,order ,scope_id, entry_date)

Comment: what is your database engine ?
what is the error message?

Comment: postgres i am using ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CLUSTERED"
LINE 1: CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX temp ON temp

Comment: Sorry, postgresql doesn't have CLUSTERED index. just create them as a normal index combined without the CLUSTERED keyword

Comment: Ok thanku ..But i had already created index on two columns so do i have to drop those and then i have to create combining these or just create without droping them.

Comment: I think create the combined first. then check if this query executes with a query plan with the newly created index and not using the other indexes (Using EXPLAIN command), then you delete the extra indexes.
good luck.

Comment: @ Atheer Mostafa Thanks It took arround 3 hrs that is fine for me.

Comment: Sudarshan ,, 3 hours for the index to create .. or for the query to run??
what was the previous execution time? thank you

Comment: @ Atheer Mostafa It took 5 minutes to create index and 3 hours to execute query.Itinitally i waited till 4 hrs and then i stopped execution.